# Why use an high-order function when a normal function would return the same result?

Tags: javascript, function, higher-order-functions

So while learning about high-order function i notice that i can have the same result while using just a normal function besides returning another function. What is the purpose of returning another function and why should i use high-order functions?

//High-order function

```
function createNumbers(p) {
    return function(x) {
        return x * p;
    };
}

let create = createNumbers(2);
console.log(create(3)); //return 6
```

//Normal function gave me the same result

```
function count(y, z) {
    return y * z;
}
console.log(count(2, 3)); // return 6
```

Answer (score 1):

The higher-order function can be saved and reused.

```
const doubler = createNumbers(2);
console.log(doubler(3));
console.log(doubler(4));
```

You can also use it as a callback.

```
const array = [1, 3, 5, 6];
const doubled_array = array.map(createNumbers(2));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer Sir, now it is clearer to me.